# Replace a custom VBA function with specific Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a lot (around 200-250 occurrences) of `MyCustomFunction` calls and I want to replace with a specific Excel-olny formula.

To save time I decided to run a script in VBA, but I don't have much experience but I will paste here what I wanted to do here.

The `MyCustomFunction` calls look like:

```
                          xval          yval       target
=@MyCustomFunction(INDEX(A1,...,1), MATCH(B2,...), C3)`
```

and want to replace above with:
`=IF(COUNT(xval)=3, yval+1, target*100)`

The VBA I'm trying:

```
Sub RegexTestingAPattern()

Dim stringOne As String
Dim regexOne As Object
Set regexOne = New RegExp

regexOne.Pattern = "MyCustomFunction\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\)"
regexOne.Global = False
stringOne = "" // do not know how to read all cells here

Set theMatches = regexOne.Execute(stringOne)
For Each Match In theMatches
  // want to replace like: Match.Groups[1].Value + "," + Match.Groups[3].Value + Match.Groups[4].Value + "," + Match.Groups[6].Value + Match.Groups[7].Value (this is C# related)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you replaced MyCustomFunction manually in a cell and then had the patience to copy (with a simple copy-paste) this cell to the others that contain MyCustomFunction, would you have the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

'1. copy manually the new formula in a cell (in this example in A1)

Sub exec_replaceMyFunc()
   Call replaceMyFunc("testt", Me.Range("A1"))
End Sub

Sub replaceMyFunc(ByVal funcToReplase As String, copyFromCell As Range)
   Dim r As Range, cl As Range, cnt As Long, f As String
   
   Set r = Me.UsedRange
   Set copyFromCell = Me.Range("A1")
   
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   
   With Application
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   End With
   
   For Each cl In r
      If cl.HasFormula Then
         f = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cl.Formula)
         If InStr(1, f, "=" & funcToReplase) = 1 Or InStr(1, f, "= " & funcToReplase) = 1 Then
            '*****************************************
            'if don't want tranform the cells use the next line
            'cl.Formula = copyFromCell.Formula
            
            '*****************************************
            'This is the default logic, copy the cell and
            'the formula references will adjust accordingly
            copyFromCell.Copy cl
            
            cnt = cnt + 1
         End If
      End If
   Next
   MsgBox ("replaced succesfully in " & cnt & " cells")
   Exit Sub
Lerr:
   With Application
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   End With

   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("replaceMyFunc>" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number> " & Err.Number)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]